# How to hide ampersand

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt when I ie name a label '&label' this means that letter 'l' will be underscored after I press 'Alt' button. And that works. Is there a way as to make this underscore dissapear after some action has been executed?

Comment: This violates standards for interface design. Generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Jay what violates std? Having ampersands or wanting them to dissapear after action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name it 'label' as the action is executed

Comment: if it was just one then maybe, but I just don't think that 'brutal' way is the way.

Comment: you can do it dynamically, replace "&" with "" loop all the labels on the form ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes if there isn't 'normal' way to do it I will consider doing it the way you've suggested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could derive your own class from QLabel where you save the original text including ampersands and have a method that removes the ampersand or uses the original text and calls QLabel::setText.

Comment: hey, thanks again with helping me setting up Qt. As for this ampersand business, I'd think that this should be 'built in' behaviour, but sadly it isn't.